# Is there a better alternative for this question?

Tags: synonyms

I translated a sentence from my native language Tamil to English using Google Translate and got this:

> What qualifications do you have to talk about it?

Is there a better alternative for this question?

Comment: It would help if some context were given

Comment: Think of a man who drinks all the time, not socially responsible, not taking care of the family. One day he yells at his friend for not being responsible. The friend gets angry and he asks this question in reply, like `What qualifications do you have to talk about it?`

Comment: What comes to mind is a saying, totally different from the sentence you tried to produce in English (which doesn't make sense in this context): "The pot is calling the kettle black", where the first man is the pot and his friend the kettle.

Comment: You got the context right. But since I translated from my native language, I got this one. Can you think of some other question which is apt for this context?

Comment: I guess something along the lines of "How do you consider yourself suitable to talk about it?"

Comment: or "Who gives you the right to judge?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand this sentence well since there's lack of further context, but a first thought is *"Have you got the authority to talk about it?"*

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to EL&U, Vivek. It would depend on the circumstances in which the question was being asked. Normally *What qualifications do you have?* would be enough, but in an interview, the interviewer might ask *Could you tell us something about your qualifications, please?*